# Implementation of linear basis function in R

Tags: r

I am trying to implement the linear model

```
y(x,w) = w0 + w1 * x1 + ... + wD * xD.
```

in R.

So far I have tried this:

```
linearbf <- function(x, w) {
  dims <- dim(x)    
  M <- t(x)
  M <- rbind(matrix(1,1,dims[1]), M)
  pred_y <- t(w)*M
  pred_y2 <- t(pred_y)
  invisible(pred_y2)
  }
```

but I am getting this error:

> "Error in t(w) * M : non-conformable arrays"

Can someone tell me what the problem is, as I have been stuck for some hours now?

**Edit:**

My sample `x` would be an array of 2 columns and 200 rows.

My sample `y` would be an array of 1 column and 2 rows.

I expect to get a 1-dimensional array as output.

Comment: Did you intend to get a cross product by `t(w)*M`? If it is the case, use `t(w) %*% M`

Comment: I then get another error: "Error in t(w) %*% M : non-conformable arguments"

Comment: Please provide a small sample input and the expected output.